# Vulkan VkBufferImageCopy for partial transfer

Tags: python, image, chromium-embedded, vulkan

In a nutshell, my problem is that when I try to update an image based on a set of dirty rectangles that offset/size of this does not match.

So, let's show the problem.
Here's the object properly rendererd:
[image: Example Figure 1]

This comes from Chromium Embedded Framework and gets properly rendered by updating the entire image - something that is usually not necessary and CEF gives you a list of rectangles that changed and need to be updated.

The full copy is succesfully achieved with:

```
def copyBuffertoImageRegion(self, topleft, size, fullsize):
    print(topleft, size, fullsize)
    with CmdBuffer(self.interface, True) as cmdbuffers:
        region = VkBufferImageCopy(
            bufferOffset=0,
            bufferRowLength=fullsize[0],
            bufferImageHeight=fullsize[1],
            imageSubresource=self.subresource,
            imageExtent=size,
            imageOffset=topleft
        )
        vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(
            cmdbuffers[0],
            self.staging.buffer,
            self.image,
            VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
            1,
            region
        )
```

The print in this case gives (0,0,0) (1920, 1080, 1) (1920, 1080)
For a full copy and this works.

However, once I try to use the dirty rects, I print for example these values:

```
(88, 88, 0) (120, 120, 1) (1920, 1080)
(88, 88, 0) (120, 120, 1) (1920, 1080)
(88, 96, 0) (120, 120, 1) (1920, 1080)
(72, 80, 0) (152, 136, 1) (1920, 1080)
(72, 80, 0) (152, 136, 1) (1920, 1080)
(80, 80, 0) (144, 136, 1) (1920, 1080)
(80, 80, 0) (136, 136, 1) (1920, 1080)
(80, 88, 0) (152, 144, 1) (1920, 1080)
(88, 88, 0) (152, 144, 1) (1920, 1080)
```

Which, if I understood the VkBufferImageCopy command right, *should* be correct?

The first tuple of the start of the dirty rect; topleft point. the second tuple is the width, height and depth of the rect and the last tuple is the full size of the image and buffer.

But, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBHv7.jpg

The offset is "wrong" - the origin of the graphic jumps around and I'm not sure about the extent.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: More info for possible further optimization:

The incoming data gets handled like this:

```
def fill(self, pointer, rects):
    rect = self.combine_rects(rects)
    ffi.memmove(self.mappedhostmemory, pointer, self.buffer.size)
    with self.interface.main_lock:
        self.image.transitionImageLayout(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL)
        self.image.copyBuffertoImageRegion(*rect,self.interface.resolution)
        self.image.transitionImageLayout(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL)
```

Pointer being this pointer:
https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/api/PaintBuffer.md#getintpointer

and mappedhostmemory being the staging buffer's mapped memory that I keep mapped.

So, even better would be if I could limit the CEF pointer -> vulkan upload even more and not even grab the entire texture and put it into the buffer, but to actually only grab the dirty parts.

Should it matter; combine_rects takes the list of dirty rects, and makes a big one out of it while also keeping the queue families' granularity in mind.

Edit 2:
Thanks to the answers so far, getting closer (thanks!), but not quite there yet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qqUw.jpg

It still jumps around, but at least it isn't data salad anymore.
This was achieved by setting

```
bufferOffset = (topleft[0]*fullsize[0]+topleft[1])*4
```

In this instance I don't need to make sure it is a multiple of 4, as it (at least on my computer, to be fixed later for general-) is on a image granularity of (8,8,8).

```
def combine_rects(self, rects):
    #start rect is *resolution, 0, 0
    left, up, width, height = self.start_rect

    for rect in rects:
        rleft, rup, rwidth, rheight = rect

        left = min(left, rleft)
        up = min(up, rup)
        width = max(width, rwidth)
        height = max(height, rheight)

    if width == self.interface.resolution[0] or height == self.interface.resolution[1]:
        #issue full copy
        return (0, 0, 0), (*self.interface.resolution, 1)

    if self.granularity_important:#granularity != (1,1,1)
        left = (left // self.granularity_x) * self.granularity_x
        up = (up // self.granularity_y) * self.granularity_y

        #safety buffer, as we may remove up to granularity-1 texels
        width += self.granularity_x
        height += self.granularity_y

        width  = width  if width  % self.granularity_x == 0 else width  + self.granularity_x - width  % self.granularity_x
        height = height if height % self.granularity_y == 0 else height + self.granularity_y - height % self.granularity_y

    return (left, up, 0), (width, height, 1)
```

In case there is an error in this function, putting that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing copies between buffers and images, you have two sets of parameters. One describes the location of interest within the image; these are defined by the `VkBufferImageCopy::image*` parameters. The other describes the location of interest within the buffer; these are defined by the `VkBufferImageCopy::buffer*` parameters.

`imageExtent` is important to both, as it describes how much data will be transferred. It does so in the space of the image, but it also affects the region of interest within the buffer.

Buffers, of course, don't contain images; they contain arbitrary data. So the way you describe the data in the buffer is different from how you would with an image.

In a buffer, image data is tightly packed; each pixel is directly adjacent to the next. And each pixel element is stored as defined by its format. The buffer part of the copy region is defined by 3 parameters.

The `bufferRowLength` is the number of pixels from one row to the next. The `bufferImageHeight` is the number of rows from one texture layer to the next.

These parameters allow you to do sub-selection from within the buffer. For example, if your buffer logically stores an image that is 100x100, and you only want to copy the first 50x50 pixels, you still provide `bufferRowLength/bufferImageHeight` values of 100x100.

It's the `imageExtent` that will prevent it from copying past the 50th pixel in each dimension. `imageExtent` determines how much data is transferred from/to the `VkImage` to/from the buffer. So if you set this to 50x50, you'll get what you need.

Note that when I say "first 50x50" pixels, I mean the top-left 50x50. If you want to copy from the top-*right* 50x50, that's a bit more of a challenge.

`bufferOffset` allows you to specify the byte offset to the start of image data. And because you can specify the row length separately from the image's extent, you can achieve a transfer from/to the top-right 50x50 by providing a `bufferOffset` of 50 * the element size. The buffer row length/height will be the same as before.

The equation that maps from image coordinates to buffer byte addresses is as follows:

```
address of (x,y,z) = region->bufferOffset + (((z * imageHeight) + y) * rowLength + x) * elementSize;
```

So, if you want to transfer from/to the bottom-left 50x50 of the buffer, you can do this. Set the `bufferOffset` to be:

```
elementSize * (50 * rowLength)
```

For the bottom-right 50x50, you would set `bufferOffset` to:

```
elementSize * ((50 * rowLength) + 50)
```

Note however that `bufferOffset` is required to be a multiple of 4 (and a multiple of the element's size, if the format is not depth/stencil). So if this were an R8 format, this would not work, since 50 is not a multiple of 4.

This also works well for 3D layer copies. The `bufferImageHeight` specifies how many rows to skip to get to the next layer.

So, to do what you're interested in, you need the following (note: I don't know Python, so I'm just guessing at the syntax):

```
bufferOffset = VkDeviceSize(((fullsize[0] * topleft.y) + topleft.x) * elementSize)

region = VkBufferImageCopy(
    bufferOffset=bufferOffset ,
    bufferRowLength=fullsize[0],
    bufferImageHeight=fullsize[1],
    imageSubresource=self.subresource,
    imageExtent=size,
    imageOffset=topleft
)
```

You'll need to calculate `elementSize` based on the format in question. Also, the above code only works for 2D copies; for 3D copies, you'll need to take into account `topleft.y` as well.

Comment: Very nice explanation, much better than the spec at any rate. Still, something is still off. I updated my question post for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your region looks bit inconsistent to me.
What is the geometry of your buffer?

If it is always full-size and you only copy subrectangles from it then the `bufferOffset` should not be `0` but set according to `topleft` (and rounded down to satisfy other restrictions).

It is probably a common mistake, so the Vulkan specification says:

> Note that `imageOffset` does not affect addressing calculations for
>   buffer memory. Instead, `bufferOffset` **can** be used to select the
>   starting address in buffer memory.

Or if the buffer is actually only the rectangle, then `bufferRowLength` and `bufferImageHeight` should not be `fullsize`.

Comment: The buffer contains the full image, always. I'm trying to only copy the changed bits to the Image at this step.
Copying only the needed bits into the buffers would be another optimization, that'd be nice to have, I guess. I'll add some info about that as an edit into the question.

Comment: So, I've set the bufferoffset equal to 
    (topleft[0]*fullsize[0]+topleft[1])*4
Which seems to get me closer to the goal, the entire object is now there as opposed to a mangled mess. It still jumps around and sometimes leaves behind and old part of the animation, so clearly I also need to adjust the other variables in some way.

Comment: @Berserker Hm, weird. Maybe first test with `0` offset to both the buffer and image and set `imageSize` to `topleft+size`. That should get rid of only the unused right and bottom edges.

Comment: @Berserker Oh, by any chance isn't the `y` coordinates of your paraneters opposite those of Vulkan `y`? If the test above discards the wrong part of the image, then that is probably the case.

Comment: @Berserker "`(topleft[0]*fullsize[0]+topleft[1])*4`" And you seem to have x and y swapped above. Should be `(topleft[1]*fullsize[0]+topleft[0])*4`?

Comment: First - buffer and image offset = 0 and extent = topleft+size does work, without visual glitches.
And turns out doing the bufferOffset as (topleft[1]*fullsize[0]+topleft[0])*4 does do the trick. So, yeah that solves it.
@krOoze helped me more in finding the answer, but for future visitors to this question, Nicol's answer is more helpful, so I'll make that one the official answer.
Also for future visitors: to fulfill the multiple of 4 requirement I just removed the granularity_important variable and made granularity the next multiple of 4